# BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 , can i save image from it. i am getting error while saving images from BackgroundSubtractorMOG2

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

i am using backgroundMOG2 to save the images with background , but the program shows the countrs , i need to save the images with backgorund.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>


int main()
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::Mat back;
    cv::Mat fore;

    //cv::Mat img;
    cv::VideoCapture cap("C:\\Users\\Pavilion\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\dynamic\\sherlock outtakes.avi");

    cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;
    bg.set("nmixtures", 3);

    //bg.bShadowDetecction=false;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>countours;

    //cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Pavilion\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\video\\video\\frames\\frame122.jpg");
    //cv::VideoCapture Cap;
    //std::vector<std::vector<cv::point> >contours;

    cv::namedWindow("frame");
    cv::namedWindow("background");

    for (;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        bg.operator()(frame, fore);
        bg.getBackgroundImage(back);
        cv::erode(fore, fore, cv::Mat());
        cv::dilate(fore, fore, cv::Mat());
        cv::findContours(fore,countours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        cv::drawContours(frame, countours, -1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
        cv::imshow("frame", back);
        // cv::imwrite("background",back);

        cv::imshow("background", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >=0) break;

}
    return 0;

}
```

this is the code i am getting error while saving image .

can someone help me to solve this

Comment: also note, that the background image is *synthesized* from the model, a very expensive process, and that most likely, you will never need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an extension (jpg, png, ...).

For example:

```
cv::imwrite("background.jpg",back);
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer,it helps me a lot.         now i want to save all images from video with contors using backgroundsubtractorMOG2()   the output of my program is showing all images in a single file i mean for single image it showing all the motion images with contors i want to save each and every image..

Comment: @OpenMinded, could you assist us open this dedicated group: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.